# Call to google maps geocode api works on local but fails on live server

Tags: php, google-maps

I have a function that takes an array of addresses, passes them into the google maps geocode api and returns a list of latitude/longitude coordinates that are then saved to a database.

It's been working perfectly in my environment (php 5.4) but I recently pushed the site live (the server has php 5.3 installed) and I noticed my lat/lng database hasn't been getting updated.

As a test I pulled out a piece of the code and ran them independently, once from my local environment and once on my server. The live code produces no results and my local code continues to produce the proper results. I'm not sure what's causing the problem as the live site is an exact replica of my local site.

Here's the code

```
$addr = '210 west 103rd street, ny 10025';

$addrencode = urlencode($addr);

$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=".$addrencode;
$json_txt = file_get_contents($url);
if (! $json_txt)
    return FALSE;
$json_arr = json_decode($json_txt, TRUE);
if ($json_arr["status"] != "OK")
    return FALSE;

$result = $json_arr["results"][0];
$ret = array(
    "addr" => $addr,
    "faddr" => $result["formatted_address"],
    "lat" => $result["geometry"]["location"]["lat"],
    "lng" => $result["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
);

print_r($ret);
```

Any idea what could be causing this to break when ran online? If I actually visit the URL with the encoded address in my browser I can also collect the results.

On local I receive:

```
Array ( [addr] => 210 west 103rd street, ny 10025 [faddr] => 210 West 103rd Street, New York, NY 10025, USA [lat] => 40.7986924 [lng] => -73.9678981 )
```

On live I receive a blank page

Comment: Maybe your server's IP is blacklisted. Sometimes a blank page is a sign of a PHP error, though. Check your logs.

Comment: Could also be an unusual setting in your php.ini like json support being disabled. This is unlikely though.

Comment: post your log from /var/logs/apache2

Comment: Is your website on a shared server?  Perhaps you need to include a key in your request.

Comment: Figured it out! It had to do with php.ini on the shared server not allowing the file_get_contents function to run